# How can I print these two string objects horizontally

Tags: java

```
public class codetest {

    public static String normalCellRepr(){
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            str.append('N').append(" - ");
        }
        str.append('N').append("   ");
        str.append('\n');
        String innerComponent = "| " + "     " + " |   ";
        str.append(innerComponent).append('\n');
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            str.append('N').append(" - ");
        }
        str.append('N').append("   ");
        return str.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String c1 = normalCellRepr();
        String c2 = normalCellRepr();
        System.out.print(c1);
        System.out.print(c2);
```

[image]

This is my output, but I want my output like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it (without using carriage returns) is to merge the two strings line-by-line in a zipper fashion:

```java
public static String merge(String str1, String str2) {
  String[] parts1 = str1.split("\n");
  String[] parts2 = str2.split("\n");
  String separator = "    ";   // space between the two strings
  StringBuilder merged = new StringBuilder();
  
  // modify this if strings are not of the same size
  for (int i=0; i < parts1.length; i++) {
    merged.append(parts1[i] + separator + parts2[i] + "\n");
  }

  return merged.toString();
}
```

Which can then be used like:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String c1 = normalCellRepr();
  String c2 = normalCellRepr();
  System.out.println(c1);
  System.out.println(c2);
  System.out.println(merge(c1, c2));
}
```